# Download Excel file

Tags: python, django, excel

I am trying to let the user download an excel file in the django admin. So far everything works, but the downloaded file is corrupt.

The relevant action in admin.py looks like this:

```
def write_status_to_excel(self, request, queryset):
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    #create workbook
    #.....
    module_dir=os.path.dirname(__file__)
    dname=r'testfile.xlsx'
    file_path=os.path.join(module_dir,dname)        
    workbook.save(filename = file_path) 

    f = open(file_path, 'r')  
    response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    #response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='text/csv') #tried this too
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.split(file_path)[-1]
    return response
```

The downloaded excel-file always has only 142 bytes (and is corrupt) whereas the file that I save on the server (with workbook.save) is ok.

I am running this so far just on the development server (django 1.7, windows 7). Could this be the cause (in which case I still would need a solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open the file as binary:

```
f = open(file_path, 'rb')
```